# How can I upgrade the built-in WLAN adapter of Samsung NC20 to support 802.11n?

Tags: upgrade, netbook, wireless-networking, 802.11n

I have a Samsung NC20 netbook with a built-in WLAN adapter Atheros AR5007EG. How can I change this component and what would be a good choice, when I want it to support 802.11n?

One option I consider i

[Intel 5300AGN](http://www.intel.com/network/connectivity/products/wireless/adapters/5000/index.htm)

There seem to be some reports indicating in the Internet indicating that these modules would be compatible with Samsung NC20, but nothing very reliable. I would prefer the Intel 5300AGN, as it operates also in the 5 GHz band.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer: apparently the Intel 5300 is the way to go, and detailed instructions to upgrade (with pictures) can be found here: [Samsung NC20 Intel 5300 WIFI upgrade and inside case shots](http://www.sammynetbook.com/plugins/forum/forum_viewtopic.php?23786) .

Answer (score 0):

Software upgrade is not possible, and hardware upgrade is hard to do, and usually rather expensive.

I suggest you buying a USB 802.11n adapter and plugging it in whenever you need more speed than your notebook originally has :)

Comment: The upgrade does only cost the price of the adapter, when I do it myself. For example, the Intel 5300AGN costs about 30 euros (44 USD). I've changed the internal WLAN adapter of some other notebooks, and it's no rocket science with some instructions or a service manual.

Plugging an additional adapter is no choice for me, as it makes the netbook too bulky.

Comment: Don't you fear that in your very notebook the adapter might be integrated, or connected with some non-standard wires? Also consider placing a USB adapter without plastic case into the notebook if there's enough place: an ugly hack, but also rather simple :)